# Raise/ Re-raise in No Limit Hold Em?

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy

My confusion is simple.
Please tell me if I am right in thinking the following things:-
1. In a 1/2 NL  game, if the conversion factor is 2x ( w.r.t Big Blind), then a person can only raise (at least) by 4, i.e. if the first person( to raise) raises by 6 to a total of 8 ( 2(big blind) + 6), then the next person( who wants to raise) has to call the 8 + raise at least by 6?
 Is this valid only in the pre-flop round or throughout the other betting rounds as well?
2. I often hear that you have to double the previous raise, is that correct? ie., if the previous person raises by 6 to a total of 8, the next person has to call the 8 and raise at least by 12?
3. If you raise some amount, do you raise "to" or raise "by" that amount. eg If I say I raise 200, does that mean I put 200 on the table or that I put 200+the amount I was supposed to put( Calling amount etc.)?

I am just a beginner in this game, and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Regarding your last point: When you say "raise, 200" it usually means "200 to go" unless the previous bet is 150 for instance so your 200 then has to mean 200 more. Usually try to avoid such misinterpretations by saying "200 **more**" when you want to raise by 200, or simply say "raise" and then push whatever chips you like, the dealer will count and declare the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this can be a house-related regulation, it's always good to look at the official [TDA](http://www.pokertda.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Poker-TDA-Rules-2015-Version-1.0-full-longform-PDF-1.pdf), if you read Rule 43, you'll find that the raiser must at least raise the ***"largest bet or raise of the current round"***.

Well what does that mean? it means that if you want to re-raise the minimum, you need to look at how much was **added** to the calling amount during the previous raise, those **added** chips are your minimum raise, so you make your call and then add **those** chips (make sure to do so in 'one move' as it's not allowed to [string bet](http://www.pokernews.com/pokerterms/string-bet.htm)).

Example:
Small blind is $1, big bling is $2, the **first** raise must simply be double the last bet, which means "$4 to go". The next re-raiser can make it at least "$6 to go" because the previous raiser added $2 to his regular call amount, the next re-raiser looks at what the previous re-raiser did, he added $2 to his regular call of $4, so that's the minimum raise, $6 + $2 = $8 to go. And so on.

Having said all that, notice that the minimum raise usually gets called because of the lack of [fold equity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_equity).